# How to retrieve value from the onclick element using IE in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have been developing a project wherein I need to login in our internal server webpage and update values in the form and submit the data to server. The main issue is, on submitting or clicking on Save button, the Internet Explorer displays a pop up button saying, "Do you need to save the data, Yes or No?". Upon selecting yes, the data gets submitted and I get another pop up button displaying, "Data submitted". However, in case there is duplicate data, it shows a Validation error pop up showing, data already exists.I'm not able to capture the value returned by the method.

Since it is a internal server link and I can't post the screenshot or link from my company desktop, **I'm sharing the bits of below HTML code from Internet Explorer.**

```
<a id= "saveButton" onclick="submitter('Save'); return false;" href="" shape= "">
```

**C# code**

```
InternetExplorerMedium IE = new InternetExplorerMedium();
HTMLDocument hdoc = new HTMLDocument();
IE.visible = true;
IE.Navigate("Internal web server page");
```

After updating all the values in form, navigating to the Save button of the form using the below code

`hdoc.all.item("saveButton").click();`

So I need to get the **return value of onclick element** ie is it true or false. I have tried `hdoc.parentWindow.execscript("submitter('Save'); return false;","javascript");` but it did nothing. It seems `InvokeScript` doesnt work with IE. Has anyone ever worked on such query?

**Note** - `InternetExplorerMedium` is the only way by which the internal server webpage is getting opened. `InternetExplorer` class was not of any help while loading the page.

Comment: Is ASP.NET being used with C# for your internal web application?

Comment: You use a design pattern like this... <a href="#" onclick="return submitter('Save');">Save</a>.... or to use the asp.net Submit button instead of a html hyperlink.....that is your submitter script returns either true or false when it validates the input fields... true means the data was submitted, false means the data has not validated and the form data is not sent to the server for updating in the database. For your asp.net projects you should use the asp.net control set eg. asp:hyperlink asp:submitbutton in your code behind... there are examples in your VSIDE template projects.

Comment: @RobParsons and @ JohnH,  I'm not implementing asp.net. it is a simple windows form where it gets data from excel n uploads to web server page.

Comment: we need to see the function submitter....from your internal (intranet)webpage....normally webforms do not use hyperlinks to submit a webform (<form> element). The message "Do you need to save the form data" suggests that your anchor tag (<a>) is navigating not submitting the form. A template webform is attached in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="myform" onsubmit="return submitter(event);" action="/account/login.php">
<label>name:<br/>
<input name="txtname" id="txtname" />
</label>
<label>secret:<br/>
<input type="password"/>
</label>
<input type="submit" value="Login"/>
<input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
</form>

<script type="javascript/text">
function submitter(evt){
// return true or false to allow the form to be submitted.
// do your field validations in this function.
}
</script>
```

To help you we need to see the markup and scripting of the internal web page you are trying to automate from C#.... It appears that that web page is incorrectly designed (does not use the above design pattern)...the process flow is
1. Load web page with a form on it.
2. User enters data into a form.
3. User clicks the submit button for the form... this triggers the form onsubmit event handler (submitter) which should then validate the data entered. If its valid submitter returns true and the form data is submitted to the server (action attribute of the form). If the data is not valid the submitter function return false, cancelling the onsubmit event handler.

Comment: Below is my submitter function in detail.js of the Webpage.
`function submitter(str)
OK = true if(str = 'save')
{
ValInit(detailFormObj);
if(prevalidationflag) preValidation();
OK=ValResult();
}

if(OK) OK=Confirm("Are you sure you want to"+str+"?");
if(OK){
if(str = "duplicate"){switchToDuplicate();
}else{
if(detailFormObj.requestID.value != 'duplicate' && detailFormObj.requestID.value != 'saveNew')
detailFormObj.requestID.value = str;
if(document.waitIndicator) enableContents(detailFormObj);
formSubmitter(detailFormObj); 
} } }`

Comment: and since it is Client side webpage,we cant change the existing function.

Comment: I tried implementing Win32 APIs using the link [https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d3f89686-e4d0-4bb1-9052-31abef2a9d2a/detecting-message-boxes-and-close-them-automaticaly?forum=winforms ] but failed. I'm not able to understand when should i call IE.HTMLDoc.parentWindow.eval("submitter('save')","javascript");

Comment: your script has errors in it function submitter(str) OK = true if(str = 'save') { ValInit(detailFormObj); if(prevalidationflag) preValidation(); OK=ValResult(); } if(OK) OK=Confirm("Are you sure you want to"+str+"?"); if(OK){ if(str = "duplicate"){switchToDuplicate(); }else{ if(detailFormObj.requestID.value != 'duplicate' && detailFormObj.requestID.value != 'saveNew') detailFormObj.requestID.value = str; if(document.waitIndicator) enableContents(detailFormObj); formSubmitter(detailFormObj); } } }